# What kind USB Cable connector of connector is this?

Tags: connector

Which connector is this? It has a USB-A Male on one side, but what is the other connector on the right?

[image: Picture: [CLICK HERE][1]]

Comment: Might be a proprietary connector. Where did you get the cable?

Comment: It looks like the non-USB end only has two pins.  Is that true?

Comment: Yes. It only has 2 pins. I got it with a RC Quadcoptor with a Li-Po battery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a variant of 1S connectors typically used for Lipo battery chargers